# php intval returning something unexpected

Tags: php

intval:

> [Get the integer value of a variable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)

```
echo intval('1000000000000');
```

returns 2147483647.

Why?

Comment: Because you can't store 1 trillion in 32 bits

Answer (score 2):

The size of an integer in PHP is platform-dependent. The documentation for [`intval()`](http://php.net/intval) clearly explains this:

> **The maximum value depends on the system.** 32 bit systems have a maximum signed integer range of -2147483648 to 2147483647. So for example on such a system, intval('1000000000000') will return 2147483647. The maximum signed integer value for 64 bit systems is 9223372036854775807.

Answer (score 1):

From the same documentation you shared..

> The maximum value depends on the system. 32 bit systems have a maximum
>   signed integer range of -2147483648 to 2147483647. So for example on
>   such a system, intval('1000000000000') will return 2147483647. The
>   maximum signed integer value for 64 bit systems is
>   9223372036854775807.

```
echo intval('1000000000000');
```

> returns 2147483647. Why?

is because the system you're trying is 32 bits system

Comment: echo intval(1000000000000) why this return 0 ?

Comment: @Muhammad Rashid I explained it in my question

Comment: @MuhammadRashid the document says `The integer value of var on success, or 0 on failure. Empty arrays return 0, non-empty arrays return 1.`

Comment: @MuhammadRashid check the examples http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php#refsect1-function.intval-examples

Answer (score 0):

**Because**

**1.** You have 32 bit systems.

**2.** That's why  you can operate  a maximum signed integer range of -2147483648 to 2147483647`.

For this value there will be no problem if You had 64 bit systems
Antother example:

On **32 bit** systems

```
echo intval('420000000000000000000'); // 2147483647
```

On **64 bit** systems

```
echo intval('420000000000000000000'); // 420000000000000000000
```